# Show that the area of the trapezoid in the picture is given by $S(a) = (a+1)\log_2(\sqrt{a})$

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(a)$ be the function with domain $\mathbb{R}$, defined by:
>
> $$f_a(x) = a - 2^{-x}$$ with $a \in ]1,+\infty[$
>
> This function is partly represented in the picture below:
>    [image]
>
> It is known that the line DC is the asymptote of $f_a(x)$ and that DA
>   is perpendicular to DC.
>
> Show that the area of the quadrilateral [ABCD] is given by $$S(a) =
> (a+1)\log_2(\sqrt{a})$$

To calculate the area I decided to use the formula for the area of trapezoids:
$$\frac{(B+b)}{2} \cdot h$$

(B is the bigger base DA, b is the smaller base CB and h is the height DC)

Finding b:

To find the smaller base I had to do $a-B0$
To find B0 I did:

$$a-2^{-0} = a-1$$

And so b is equal to 1.

Finding B:

Since DC is the asymptote of $F_a(x)$ then the height is a, so B = a.

My problem is finding the height h. I did:

$$0 = a - 2^{-x} \Leftrightarrow a = -2^{-x} \Leftrightarrow -a = 2^{-x} \Leftrightarrow -a = \frac{1}{2^x} \Leftrightarrow -\frac{1}{a} = 2^x \Leftrightarrow x = \log_2(-\frac{1}{a})$$

Then I replaced the values in the formula:

$$\frac{(B+b)}{2} \cdot h \Leftrightarrow \frac{(a+1)\cdot \log_2(-\frac{1}{a})}{2} \Leftrightarrow \frac{a+1}{2} \log_2(\sqrt{a})$$

I put this graph and $S(a)$ in the calculator to compare them and they give different values, so I know this is incorrect.

What did I do wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: $0 = a - 2^{-x} \iff a = -2^{-x}\;\;$ Well, no.

Comment: @dxiv Oh. Silly mistake

Comment: @dxiv So I get that $h = \log_2(\frac{1}{a})$, but that still doesn't work. I do $ \frac{(a+1)\cdot \log_2(\frac{1}{a})}{2} $. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You mean $h$ to be positive, so $h=-x=\log_2 a$.

Comment: @dxiv Ah. I see